# what is MD means in mobile developing?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, html-framework-7

In some mobile develop website like framework7,can see words MD and ios,and what is MD means in this circumstance，is it means android and is it has some relateionship with HD?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be for [Material Design](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) But without the proper context hard to say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the Framework7, the MD refers to **Material Design**. They have even themes which suggest iOS or MD meaning MaterialDesign theme which follows all the google material design guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in prior answers, MD in Framork7 stands for [Material Design](https://material.io/) which is the Android implementation of the Framework. Framework7 was initailly an ios hybrid app tool. Material Design, as you can see from the website, is an entire theming system developed by Google, and can used for a lot more than just Framework7 app development.